# javascript swap text block onclick anchor link

Tags: javascript, text, onclick, swap

This should be easy but it's not working properly...  I am quite rusty on javascript and can't figure out what it is I am missing.

I have a navbar that I'd like to disappear when person clicks on small arrow, leaving just a 2nd arrow.  When user clicks on 2nd arrow, nav bar reappears.  All of the navbar is in one  tag.  The nav menu itself is quite long, one reason, I want to give user ability to toggle it on and off.

Javascript function in head is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function collapseMenu()
{document.getElementById("navbar").innerHTML ='<td id=navbar2><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="collapseMenu('navbar2');"><img src="arrow.gif"></a></td>';
}</script>
```

Text on page is:

```
<div id='navbar'>
<td>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="collapseMenu('navbar');"><img src="arrow.gif"></a>
</td>
</div>
```

Placing id in the div tag, it shows the arrow when you click on the link but doesn't remove the old html between the div tags.  Same thing using span instead of div and no difference between single and double quotes.  When I move the id="navbar" to the  tag, the nav bar does disappear but it leaves the background color unchanged for the size of the old td tag.  I would like it to go blank except for tiny arrow.  So question 1 is why are div and span not working, or alternatively, td leaving background color in old space.

2nd question is how to specify innerHTM in text through a variable.  It would be nice not to have to put this all in function in header.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Is an example possible? Maybe a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: cut and past following into .txt file and rename .htm and you'll see what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what a jsfiddle is but following code reproduces problem if put in .htm file.  Thx.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideBar()
{document.getElementById("navbar").innerHTML ='<td>show navbar</td>';
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideBar2()
{document.getElementById("navbar2").innerHTML ='<td>show navbar</td>';
}</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width=500>
id in td tag
<tr>
<td rowspan=3 bgcolor="yellow" id="navbar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hideBar('navbar');">hide 

menu</a><br>menu1<br>menu2<br>menu3<br>menu4
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>lots of content here<br>more content<br>more content<br>more<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah</td>
</tr>

</table>


<table width=500>
id in div tag
<tr>
<div id="navbar2">
<td rowspan=3 bgcolor="yellow">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hideBar2('navbar2');">hide 

menu</a><br>menu1<br>menu2<br>menu3<br>menu4
</td></div>
</tr>
<tr><td>lots of content here<br>more content<br>more content<br>more<br>blah<br>blah<br>blah</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked when I moved link to function out of div to be replaced so I am thinking using div you cannot replace content that contains the link to replace.  Seems there ought to be a way to do this common swap, however,

Answer (score 0):

Following leaves one line of background expand gif.  Moving the gif outside the div throws off cell alignment.  Realize that tables are no longer considered best practice but redoing table structure of whole site would be large undertaking.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleBar(obj) {
                var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
                if (navbar.style.display == "none") {
                    navbar.style.display = "";
                    obj.innerHTML = "<img src='images/collapse.gif' alt='Hide Menu'>";
                } else {
                    navbar.style.display = "none";
                    obj.innerHTML = "<img src='images/expand.gif' alt='Show Menu'>";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body><table><tr><td valign="top">
        <div style="background-color:lightgrey;text-align:left;padding-left:4px;width:80px;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleBar(this);"><img src="images/collapse.gif" 

    alt="Hide Menu"></a>
            <div id="navbar">menu1<br>menu2<br>menu3<br>menu4</div>
        </div>
    <td valign="top"><table><tr style="background-color:blue;"><td><font 

    color="white">Title</font></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Body Text</td></tr></table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Solution!  Got rid of background color behind expand taking single color attribute out of div around navbar and instead bracketing innerhtml for collapse and expand as well as collapse link and navbar in body with respectve divs that that had own color attributes, e.g. obj.innerHTML = "<div style='background-color:white'><img src='images/expand.gif' alt='Show Menu'></div>", in other words colored each thing separately.  Trick to this whole thing was proper placement of style tags in divs, spans, tds. etc.