# Swap images with single button JavaScript function using %

Tags: javascript, image, function

Fellow Programmers! A wonderful afternoon (or whatever the case) to you!
With some assistance of fellow users I was able to manage getting an image to change back and forth between a second image every couple seconds. It's awesome! So I counted out some of the math with the % operator, and sure enough when the image first displays, I get the default broken link image of the browser, but after the 2 seconds everything goes as planned.
So begins this investigative experiment.
I decided instead of swapping automatically, lets make the swap with a button as to be able to investigate the page as long as I would like. But who want's to do the exact same thing again, why not learn another cool trick along the way. That trick is to display both of the images at the same time, such that when the button is clicked they swap places. Same math, different effect for the user. Isn't that awesome!

The goal: 
display two images and below them one button. When the button is clicked the images are to swap places. The images that was on the left should be on the right, the one on the right ought now be on the left. Use no jQuery, this is after all a JavaScript experiment (and I have yet to learn much jQuery but I can't wait to get there!)

Browser error console messages:
Interestingly enough firefox give me nothing. I open the browser, load the page in it from VS 2012 clear the error conslole, refresh the page. And nothing.
In chrome (my default browser) however, I get a localhost pic src 404 not found.
I find this strange because this code is on a page that happens to have other code which references those same pictures and works fine. The 2 second auto img flip thing being some of that other code.

debugging:I'm to much of a noob to know what's going on with that. I get the basic Idea and looked into it some. On the VS site there's all this info about setting breaking points and running multiple instance of VS to do something with another engine. I will soon be on youtube to hammer that out. I apologize however, if there is some simple debug fix to this and I should have witnessed it. Hammering through my 2nd web class and that topic has not been covered :(

Here are articles that I found similar to my question.
This was helpful to see how they had set up the if else:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671442/swap-image-with-onclick-not-responding
all in all that turned out to be more that I could read, clearly the writer is more advanced than I.
a second: [javascript swap text block onclick anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066047/javascript-swap-text-block-onclick-anchor-link/10164092#10164092) a bit of an information overload I think. There was a lot going on with that, but I never managed to change any of my code after reading through it.

If your curious here is the VS article I briefly mentioned:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/28/javascript-native-interop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

And here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function swap_pics() {
                var c = 1
                //I had:
                //var andy_arr = ["andy_white.jpg","andy_black.jpg"];
                var andy_src1 = "andy_left.jpg";
                var andy_src2 = "andy_right.jpg";
                c = ((c + 1) % 2);
                if (c == 0) {

                    //I was using an array which looked like:
                    // document.getElementById('andy_left').src = "andy_arr[0]";
                    // document.get ... _right').src = andy_arr[Math.abs(c-1)];
                    //0-1 abs = 1
                    //1-1 = 0, so It looks like it should now toggle.

                    document.getElementById('andy_left').src = andy_src1;
                    document.getElementById('andy_right').src = andy_src2;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('andy_left').src = andy_src2;
                    document.getElementById('andy_right').src = andy_src1;
                }
            }
        </script>    
        <div id="mini_lab_5">
        <img src="" 
            id="andy_left"
            height="100"
            width="100"
            />
        <img src=""
            id="andy_right" 
            height="100"
            width="100"
            />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Swap" 
            onclick="swap_pics();
    "/>
    </div>
```

Thanks for being a part of the community and making it great!

Comment: What URL do you see for the 404 in Chrome?

Comment: You should debug using Chrome's or Firefox's Developer Tools.

Comment: inside swap_pics you have `var c = 1` so your result will always be the same.

Comment: The URL is a localhost address that it would not let me paste in the question - here it is:
 http://localhost:29729/JavaScript/andy_left.jpg 

Ill be sure and gather some information on the developer tools, thanks!

I've changed var c = 1 to 0, I was thinking that c= c+1%2 should change its value in var regardless. Now that it is 0 there are far more of the 404 errors when I push the button, defiantly progress! thanks!

Comment: Make sure that your image files are in the same folder as your html file, or that you affect the src attribute to the relative path of the images if they are not in the same folder. Also, you should declare your var c = 0; outside of the swap_pics function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the images directly to your img tags like this :

```
<img src="andy_left.jpg" 
            id="andy_left"
            height="100"
            width="100"
            />
        <img src="andy_right.jpg"
            id="andy_right" 
            height="100"
            width="100"
            />
```

Then your images should appear by default in your page, if not your links to the images are not good.

Then you could replace your current swap_pics function with the following :

```
function swap_pics() {
                var andy_left = document.getElementById('andy_left'),
                    andy_right = document.getElementById('andy_right'),
                    andy_left_src = andy_left.src,
                    andy_right_src = andy_right.src;

                andy_left.src = andy_right_src;
                andy_right.src = andy_left_src;
            }
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/X9YTP/

Comment: Perfect! i'm crunched for time but i'll be reviewing and absorbing as much of this as I can asap. Thank you very much for the assistance! love it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go good luck.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function switchImage () {
    var imgleft = document.getElementById('image1'),
        imgright = document.getElementById('image2'),
        img_left_src = imgleft.src,
        img_right_src = imgright.src;

    imgleft.src = img_right_src;
    imgright.src = img_left_src;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="image1" src="./home-cat.jpg" />
        <button id="butnum" onclick="switchImage();">Switch</button>
        <img id="image2" src="./images.jpeg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```